# I can't display json with select option (Laravel Vue)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I want to display the value in Options with province_id and province.
but in the options it always appears in JSON format. please help me i'm stuck

this my create.js

```
 changeShippingCountry(country) {
        this.$set(this.form.shipping, 'country', country);

        this.fetchStates(country, (states) => {
            this.$set(this.states, 'shipping', states);
            this.$set(this.form.shipping, 'state', '');
        });
    },

    fetchStates(country, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: route('provinces'),
            dataType: "json",
        }).then(callback);
    },
```

and this billing_detail.blade.php

```
<input
                        type="text"
                        name="billing[state]"
                        :value="form.billing.state"
                        id="billing-state"
                        class="form-control"
                        v-if="! hasBillingStates"
                        @change="changeBillingState($event.target.value)"
                    >

                    <select
                        name="billing[state]"
                        v-model="form.billing.state"
                        id="billing-state"
                        class="form-control arrow-black"
                        v-else
                    >
                        <option value="">{{ trans('storefront::checkout.please_select') }}</option>

                        <option
                            v-for="(name, code) in states.billing"
                            :value="code"
                            v-text="name"
                        >
                        </option>
                    </select>
```

this is result in options

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how your backend data is provided in PHP, but I'm making the assumption here that `states.billing` is an array of objects, each object with the elements `province_id` and `province` in it.

In the [vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html), you can read that the 2nd arguments you put in between brackets at the front of a v-for loop differ, depending on whether your `v-for` loops over an array or an object.

If it is an **array**, the documentation reads:

> v-for also supports an optional second argument for the index of the current item.

If it is an **object**, the documentation reads:

> You can also provide a second argument for the property’s name (a.k.a. key)

Considering that you are looping over an array (of objects), you should probably update your `v-for` loop to something like this:

```
<option
  v-for="(item, index) in states.billing"
  :value="item.province_id"
  :key="index"
>
  {{ item.province }}
</option>
```

Note that I'm using the index for the [key attribute](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#key) here. If your province_id is unique, you can also do the following:

```
<option
  v-for="item in states.billing"
  :value="item.province_id"
  :key="item.province_id"
>
  {{ item.province }}
</option>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, Gerard, I get values from **create.js**

`computed: {
       

        hasBillingStates() {
            return Object.keys(this.states.billing).length !== 0;
        },

   
        },
    },
};`

Comment: @AgusNawan I updated my answer to be more clear. Does this solve your problem?